# View date filter using years as an offset

Tags: views, 8, datetime

Is there a way to use years as a date filter offset?  What I want is to set it so that it it loads all content from the start of the previous year. So >= 01-01-2017 this year, >= 01-01-2018 next year, etc.  Is there a way to do that in the View configuration so that it's dynamic?  I'm sure I could do it with custom code by altering the query, but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: Have you tried a <= filter?

Comment: I would need it to be dynamic.  So if I put a specific date I would have to update the configuration every year, which I don't want.  What I want is to set it so that it it loads all content from the start of the previous year.  So >= 01-01-2017 this year, >=01-01-2018 next year, etc.

Comment: `now -1 year` default value?

Comment: @Kevin  Nope that only covers 12/2017 to 12/2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was more of a PHP strtotime() question.  I just had to figure out the appropriate phrase to get the time frame I wanted, which is: "first day of january last year". I placed that phrase in the filter's offset value.